# why Segmentation fault: 11 occurred for my C code?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, c-strings

I tried to write a function that deletes each character in string `s1` that matches any character in the string `s2`. 
Here is the testing code for the squeeze method.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void squeeze(char s1[], char s2[]);

int main()
{
    char s1[20] = "HelloWorld", s2[20] = "ol"; 
    squeeze(s1, s2); 
    printf("%s\n", s1); 
    return 0; 
}

void squeeze(char s1[], char s2[])
{
    int i, j, k; 
    k = 0; 
    for (i = 0; s1[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; s2[j] != '\0'; ++j) {
            if (s1[i] != s2[j])
                s1[k++] = s1[i];
        }
    }
    s1[k] = '\0';
}
```

When I run this code, terminal always gives `Segmentation fault: 11`.
Could anyone please give me any hints why this happens?

Comment: please fix your indenting

Comment: Please try debugging your code!

Comment: Agree with @kiner_shah — you need to learn how to use a debugger. The problem here is that the value of `k` is going beyond the end of the `s1` array.

Comment: Try debugging (for example by printing `i`, `j`, `k`, `s1` and `s2` in each loop step). The best way to debug is to use debugger of course but for quick debug printing values may be sufficient.

Comment: You are incrementing k when you should not and you are not incrementing it when you should.

Comment: You're checking whether ANY character in s2 doesn't match s1[i]. What you want to be checking is whether ALL characters in s2 don't match. You could use a flag or a break statement.

Comment: @Sanjay-sopho `char for[]` <==> `char *foo` in function argument because array decay in pointer.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...). Improve your code till you get no warnings. **Use the debugger** (`gdb`) to run it step by step. Be afraid of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int found(char *str, char c) { //  return 1 if c is found in str
  for (size_t i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    if (str[i] == c) {
      return 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

static void squeeze(char *a, char *b) {
  size_t k = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; i++) { // use size_t to iterate on a c-string
    if (found(b, a[i]) != 1) { 
      a[k++] = a[i]; // copy only if a[i] is not in b
    }
  }
  a[k] = '\0';
}

int main(void) {
  char a[] = "HelloWorld"; // you should let auto size
  char b[] = "ol";         // and separate declaration

  squeeze(a, b);

  printf("%s\n", a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your code is `s1[k++] = s1[i];`

Try to use new array

See Following Code

```
#include<stdio.h>

char *squeeze(char s1[], char s2[]);

int main()
{
    char s1[20] = "HelloWorld", s2[20] = "olH";

    squeeze(s1, s2);

    return 0;
}


char *squeeze(char s1[], char s2[])
{
    int i, j, k;

    k = 0;

    char arr[100]; // new array

    int flag = 0;
    for (i = 0; s1[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        flag = 0;

        for (j = 0; s2[j] != '\0'; ++j) {
            if (s1[i] == s2[j])
            {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (flag == 0)
        {
            arr[k++] = s1[i];
        }
    }

    arr[k] = '\0';

    printf("%s",arr);
}
```